How to download transcripts with certain words in description in the ENSEMBL. description?
I want to download all human tumor transcripts (in FASTA and GTF format) in ENSEMBL and I have a skim on Customize your download and Fetch data programmatically, but none of them mentioned how to download the transcripts when the keyword appeared in description.
It seems that I have to obtain all the transcript_id so that I can get the transcripts. What if, how I achieve these id?


This doesn't seem to be a biology question, but an administrative one. Shouldn't you be contacting customer services at ensembl.org?
